# Aliases in bashrc are not working - everything else is

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04

given this ~/.test file on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
alias ll='ls -la'
echo "TEST"
```

when I source ~/.test I get TEST printed to the terminal but the alias is not working.

Further information in response to questions:

This is a terminal copy/paste for illustration:

```
kontrol@smartxffts:~$ cat .test
alias ll='ls -la'
echo "TEST"

kontrol@smartxffts:~$ source .test
TEST
kontrol@smartxffts:~$ ll
ll: command not found
kontrol@smartxffts:~$ alias ll='ls -la'
kontrol@smartxffts:~$ ll
ll: command not found
```

The alias command works as expected with other accounts on the same system. This user where it doesn't work was created as follows:

```
sudo mkdir /home/kontrol
sudo useradd -u 1001 -b /home -s /bin/bash -G adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare kontrol
sudo chown kontrol:kontrol kontrol/
```

Still stumped...!

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.

Comment: Please, show how exactly do you source `~/.aliases`.

Comment: well, can't bloody format in a response. see edited question

Comment: Is it possible you've accidentally aliased or otherwise redefined `alias`? What does `type -a alias` say?

Answer (score 1):

There was a ll alias in the .bashrc with the option --color=auto. Removing that solved this. That still doesn't explain why a) the new alias of ll didn't overwrite the old one, and b) why the option --color=auto made it not work. Other ls aliases use that option and they work.

Comment: Can you repeat the experiment in your post with `env -i bash --norc` and then add the other alias as required to reproduce?